# How to make Custom Xib Cell Resize Correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xib

I'm trying to make a custom xib cell resize based on really how much information the user enters.

I have tried setting the constraints of the xib cell, like this [Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujoN2.png)
I only have top and bottom constraints on the Label and the Date.

In the viewDidLoad() of the viewcontroller containing the cell and tableview i have

```
  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

and I also have set

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 250
    }
```

[GIF of Resize Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vC0h.gif)

Comment: first set the trailing constraints of UILabel.

Comment: and  number of line should be 0 .